# Can I remap the button on my headphones to control the pandora app on windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I would like to write a program that can intercept the windows message that is sent when I press the button on my apple headphones and remap that to send a message to my desktop pandora app to play/pause.  Is there already a utility that accomplishes this?  Does the .NET framework give me access to these messages?  Would I be able to access the message before it is sent to it's default program?

Comment: I would start by researching the headphones to find out what is communicated when the button on your headphones is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there already a utility that accomplishes this?

No clue. Probably not. SO isn't for recommendation questions anyways.

> Does the .NET framework give me access to these messages?

No. Not easily anyways.

> Would I be able to access the message before it is sent to it's
>   default program?

I don't know about timing, but you should be able to access it. You'll need to set up a **hook** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx)). Unfortunately, this is in the Windows API and so you'll need to use PInvoke to actually call the native (C++) methods needed.